# Connection String Proxy?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

My application uses a bunch of Service classes, many of which have a backing Repository class.  When my application starts up, I create a new Unity container with handles creating all of my Service and Repository classes and does all of the dependency injection.  The examples that I've seen say that it's bad practice to have the Unity container by a global container, so it goes out of scope after it's finished creating all of the objects that it needs to create.  Then those objects get passed around throughout the rest of the program.

My problem is that I have a "settings" window which lets the user change the database name and server.  However, all of the Services objects already have backing Repository objects which have been created by injecting the original database name and server.  So I have to change the database connection string for all of those Repository objects that have already been created.

I was thinking about making something like an `IDatabaseConnectionStringProxy` interface and having all of my Repository objects have a reference to a single object of that type, rather than each Repository storing its connection string explicity.  Then I could just have my "settings" window update the connection string on that single proxy object which all of the Repository classes are pointing to.  Would this be good design or is it a bad way of doing things?  If this isn't a good idea, how should I handle this?

Comment: Is it even meaningful to create those objects before asking for the user input? Is there a default connection string that is used until the user changes the setting?

Comment: Yes, by default the program is installed using a default connection string.  Then if the user ever changes the connection, then that database name and server become the new defaults the next time that the program is started.  Pretty much everything that the program does requires database access, so it needs to create those objects from the get-go.

Comment: *"the next time that the program is started"* Can't you just save the new connection string in the config file and carry on, then?

Comment: I do save it there.  The next time the program starts, I don't have a problem because all of the dependency injection is done anew and everything is great.  My difficulty is in updating all of the connection strings that are stored in each Repository object during the same execution of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a variation of the quite exotic *Future* lifestyle described on page 272 in [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG). Instead of inventing a new interface, I think you should be able to address this concern with a [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

First, let's imagine what the types involved look like. It sounds like you have some repository interfaces. Let's call a representative Repository `IFooRepository`:

```
public interface IFooRepository
{
    Foo Read(int id);
}
```

It also sounds like you have concrete implementations that talk to a database. For good measure, let's give the concrete classes [Inspection Properties](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/04/structural-inspection), so that we can query the repository object to ask it which connection string it uses:

```
public class SqlFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    private const string connectionString;

    public SqlFooRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        if (connectionString == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("connectionString");

        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return this.connectionString; }
    }

    public Foo Read(int id)
    {
        // SQL query code goes here...
    }
}
```

This enables you to create a Decorator (or perhaps it's a [Decoraptor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/24/decoraptor)):

```
public class ConnectionstringAwareFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    private SqlFooRepository repo;

    public Foo Read(int id)
    {
        var connectionstring =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString;

        if (this.repo == null ||
            this.repo.ConnectionString != connectionString)
            this.repo = new SqlFooRepository(connectionString);

        return this.repo.Read(id);
    }
}
```

The benefit of this design is that it completely shields the client code from dealing with the management aspects of discovering new connection strings. All the client sees is `IFooRepository`.

Do note, though, that the above example isn't thread-safe. If you need to use this solution in a multi-threaded environment, you'll need to make it thread-safe.

Since the `ConnectionstringAwareFooRepository` class reads from the configuration file, I would strongly recommend that you put it in the same part of your code base as your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot).

Comment: That's an interesting solution.  I've also never heard the term _Future_ lifestyle before.  Thanks for introducing me to that.  I'm going to read about it.  I'm a little worried about having that `ConfigurationManager` reference within `ConnectionStringAwareFooRepository` (particularly with it being a static class) because I've been working hard to make sure that all of my dependencies are injected, and `ConfigurationManager` looks like it's introducing an external dependency.  In your opinion, is that type of "configuration setting" external dependency OK?

Comment: @BenRubin That's why I recommended that you put that class in your Composition Root. You'll need to read configuration values from `.config` files somewhere, and that somewhere is the Composition Root.

Comment: @BenRubin Still, if you rather prefer to put `ConnectionstringAwareFooRepository` somewhere else, then inject an Abstract Factory that can read the connection string for you, and implement that Abstract Factory by reading from the configuration file.

Comment: So in your example, `ConfigurationManager` is a property of the repository, and saying `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString` causes it to read the current value from the application's configuration, rather than the program reading the connection string at the composition root and caching that value.  Is that correct?  Sorry for asking so many questions; I just want to make sure I understand this well.

Comment: @BenRubin `ConfigurationManager` is [`ConfigurationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager)...

Comment: Oh ok.  I misunderstood.